# When viewing a commit on GitHub, there is a file listed with #--># appended to it (see picture). What does it mean?

Tags: github

[GitHub Arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8jfIl.png)

I'm viewing the diffs introduced by a commit to a repository on GitHub, and one of the files has the file name with this mysterious (to me) string appended to it. The file name is gulpfile.js and it is followed by 100755 --> 100644. Does anyone know what it means?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically this means that the commit removed the "executable" bit from the file, i.e. `chmod -x` was done by the commit author.

---

The numbers are in the same format as st_mode in Unix stat().

- The first `10` (octal) indicates a regular file. (04 is a directory, 12 is a symlink, 16 is a Git-specific value indicating a submodule.)
- The next `0644` (octal) are the regular Unix permissions – the file is readable by everyone and writable by its owner. Compared to that, `0755` also means the file is *executable* by everyone.

(Note that Git doesn't store the real permissions, only a look-alike: it *always* stores 0755 if the file is executable and 0644 if it is not, and 0000 for directories and other non-file objects.)

You can see these values for local Git repositories by running `git ls-tree <treeish>`, e.g.:

```
$ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob e42c7ff372783714c873fb8f33c7c04fba1d7e02    Plain_file.txt
040000 tree c909f07b68d787edabba4384f105fc37ed942e17    This_is_a_directory
120000 blob ba6b7e01db412305ff893b6c1cf279094f5656ac    Symlink_to_a_file.txt
160000 commit 6a41d623cdd0f93f16dff679963d2a5b4f856bdb  Some_submodule
100755 blob fe7ce105da1306e8648d8e2849cc3c72ca512d20    An_executable_script.sh
```